# Percorrer linhas de uma tabela dentro de loops

Tags: php, html, mysqli

O que pretendo fazer é marcar horas e datas no *front-end* de acordo com os registros de uma tabela, porém com o código que possuo só consigo marcar a primeira linha da tabela. Como conseguir percorrer toda a tabela, marcando todas as datas correspondentes?

Tive um certo êxito com um outro `while` no lugar do `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` utilizando `mysqli_fetch_array()` porém ele repete a quantidade de linhas da tabela, multiplicando as horas do *front-end*. Segue meu código:

```
<div class="row">
   <?
   for ($i=0; $i < 12; $i++) { 
      $justDay=date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+$i days"));
      $days=formatDt(date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+$i days")));
      $dweek= strftime('%A', strtotime("+$i days, today"));
   ?>
   <div class="col-md-1 bord-head-table text-center">
      <span class="text-primary"><?= $days;?><br><!--linha exbe semana--></span><br>
      <span class="text-white fontweek"><?=utf8_encode($dweek); ?></span>
      <hr class="border-lime">
      <!-- chama tabela horas-->
      <? $sql = "SELECT * from horas";
      $qr=mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
      $it=0;
      while ($ft=mysqli_fetch_array($qr)) { 
         $it++;
         $sqlAula = "SELECT * from monta_aula";
         $qrAula=mysqli_query($conexao,$sqlAula);
         $ftAula=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qrAula);
         $hrAula=$ftAula['hora_inicio_aula'];

         /* compara hora e data da tabela aula com a hora e data do front end e contorna o horário correspondente ao cadastrado no banco, na tabela aula*/
         if ($hrAula == $ft['hora'] and $justDay == $ftAula['dia_aula']) {
            $hc="border-class";
         } else{
            $hc="text-green-d";
         }
      ?>
      <div class="bord-hours">
         <a href="#" class="<?=$hc;?>">
         <?=$ft['hora'];?>
         </a><br>
      </div>
      <?    }//while ?>
   </div>
   <!--col md 1 - representa cada coluna, com data, dia da semana e horários (de 08:00:00 às 21:00:00)-->
   <? }//for ?>
</div>
<!--row-->
```

Tabela a percorrer:

[image: Banco de Dados]

Tabela Horas:

[image: Banco de Dados - Horas]

Front End:

[image: FRONT END]

Comment: Seu código está um pouco confuso pra mim. você está fazendo dois selects, um de horas que não tenho como saber quais são os dados dessa tabale, e outro repetindo em loop dentro do while. 

Acho que você resolveria tudo isso em comparação com um único select. E montando essa tabela de horários ao mesmo tempo que ja faz a comparação com os dados retornados. 

Teria que ser analisado com mais tempo e reestruturar o seu código. Mas sobre o `mysqli_fetch_array($qr)`, ja tentou usar assim: `mysqli_fetch_array($qr, MYSQLI_ASSOC)`. Creio que **MYSQLI_ASSOC** evitaria a repetição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que você tenha que criar alguma relação entre o seu `for()` e as consultas que estão sendo feitas posteriormente.

A cada *loop* do `for()` você busca todos os horários em todos os dias cadastrados. Não teria que trazer somente os registros daquele dia específico que é calculado em `$justDay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+$i days'))`?

Outro detalhe é que quando você faz `$hrAula = $ftAula['hora_inicio_aula']`, você está pegando só o primeiro registro da consulta que pode retornar *n* registros.

Você pode tentar fazer da seguinte forma então:

```
$sqlAula = "SELECT id_monta_aula FROM monta_aula WHERE dia_aula = '" . $justDay . "' AND hora_inicio_aula = '" . $ft['hora'] . "' LIMIT 1";
```

Dessa forma, a cada vez que o `while()` for executado, a consulta vai buscar uma aula (observe o `LIMIT 1`) no dia calculado lá em `$justDay` e em cada horário da *query* `"SELECT * from horas"` para esse dia.

Portanto, você só precisará verificar se existe alguma aula nessa consulta:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($sqlAula) == 1)
{
    $hc = 'border-class'; // Tem aula nesse dia e horário!
}
else
{
    $hc = 'text-green-d'; // Não tem aula...
}
```

Não recomendo muito utilizar `*` nas consultas, por isso retirei, porém depois você pode colocar os campos que precisar.

Lembrando que em termos de performance, também não é muito recomendado que você traga as horas do banco de dados como está sendo feito. Entretanto, acredito que irá funcionar normalmente.

O motivo é bem simples, o `for()` se repete 12 vezes, ou seja, a cada vez que se repete executará **1** consulta trazendo os horários e mais **14** consultas abaixo (uma para cada horário da tabela). Isso tudo será equivalente a `12 * 15 = 180` consultas.

Espero ter ajudado! :)